# Can't open index.php by default with Nginx on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2

I cannot access `index.php` when I go to my Amazon EC2 public IP.

I have `php5-fpm` and `php5-mysql` installed.

It shows 404 error when I open http://publicIP/index.php.
I have my `index.php` file in `/var/www/html`.

The following is the contents of `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php5-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: That configuration you've posted - how are you including it into the main nginx configuration? It's quite possible that it's just being skipped.

Comment: What should I do then ? @RobbieAverill  Should I check my other nginx configs ?

Comment: Break it deliberately (syntax error or something) then run `nginx -t` to test the syntax and make sure it says something broke

Comment: I made a syntax error and then tested,it showed: `nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: Now I am geting:  `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "<!DOCTYPE" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/index.html:6
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`  @RobbieAverill

Comment: When I do `nginx -t` after fixing the error in the config file above. I get the `<!DOCTYPE" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/index.html` error

Comment: Why is `index.html` in your nginx configuration path? It should be in `/var/www/html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove index.html from sites-enabled folder using
`sudo rm index.html`
and then restart nginx `sudo service nginx restart`.Now,when you test using the command `sudo nginx -t`.It should show success.